# Aggregate census tract data to county level

Tags: arcgis-desktop, census, aggregation

I have data on a census tract basis but I am having trouble aggregating them to county level. Is there any tool to do it in ArcGIS?

Comment: You are probably looking for Dissolve http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have your county data you can use the spatial join tool. There you can set (via right click on the fields in the lower section) that they should be joined via sum, min, max, median, and so on.